# Element not visible in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-webdriver, click, element

I have to automate a  scenario, where I have to click on a link. It is working fine, but some times it will take more time, so that the script is failing. Is there any solution for this.

Please help

Comment: try using `explicit/implicit` waits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait till element is available for click.

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webDriver, timeoutInSeconds);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id<locator>));
```

Comment: Hi Naveen, In this case the element is visible, but after clicking that element it takes time to load the contents of the page

Comment: Then find an element of page which loads in the last after page load and check the availability of that element. Or if it is a Ajax call using jquery you can check the status of completion of Ajax call